# Curl –F to Ruby on Rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

I have been given a website to fix that appears to use a Curl –F statement to pass the contents of a text file from a server to a website, which is written in Ruby on Rails.  When it is sent to the website, something is triggered that is supposed to update a members MySQL database.

Unfortunately, I have never used Ruby on Rails or Curl statements, so I have a learning curve.

I found the controller in rails that is supposed to do all the work for updating the database, but I cannot find out what is needed to trigger the controller.

There is nothing in the website directory where the curl statement is pointing and I get a 404 Error saying that the page cannot be found. Is there supposed to be a page there?

How do I get the controller to trigger and update the database?

Some Code:

Curl Statement

```
# push to website 
curl -F token=tysh982k8s -F data=@/directorypath/to/memberinfo.txt http://www.website.com/api/member/update
```

Controller

```
class Api::MembersController < ApplicationController
 def update
response_string = ""
response_status = ""
sent_members = []

if params[:token] == 'tysh982k8s'
  response_status = "OK"
  member_data = params[:data].read

  # Parse the line
  member_data.split(/\r?\n/).each do |l|
    new_attributes = Member.attributes_from_string(l)
    sent_members << new_attributes[:account_number]
    current_member = Member.where(:account_number=>new_attributes[:account_number]).first
```

Comment: The URL might be wrong, try members instead of member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller is triggered via the HTTP GET request that the Curl statement generates. To update the website you need to run the curl command.

the curl statement is passing 2 parameters a token = 'tysh982k8s' (which is acting in a similar way to a password)

and the data parameter, which contains the info from the file which is going to be used to update the database.

There won't be a page at that location. The Rails method is as follows.

HTTP REQUEST -> config/routes.rb 
This file determines which controller to forward the web address to. ie. in this case GET 'members/update' => 'members#update'  forwards the address 'members/update' to the update function in the members controller.

Members controller 
The controller gets the token & data variables, accesses them via params[:token], params[:data], the controller is responsible for talking to the database. It can take those parameters & update the database.

If you don't want to use curl and instead want to trigger the update via your web browser you should be able to use 'http://www.website.com/members/update?token=tysh982k8s&data='data string'

Comment: That is a great explanation of what Rails does to trigger the controller.  I made the change from member to members in the curl statement like Srdjan suggested and it worked.